# Embed website in an iframe and hide certain elements

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a client that wants to be able to embed their website into their distributors websites.

Basically inserting it in an `iframe`. But they want certain elements of their website that are normally visible to not appear on the embedded version.

Is there a way to embed a website in an `iframe` and use `css` to hide specific `div` id's to achieve this?

Comment: you can not change any contain inside iframe if iframe is not from same domain.  try google with this: "stackoverflow iframe same domain origin"

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy

Comment: Is there another way to do this then? If not using an iframe to achieve the goal?

Answer (score -2):

you can use following code in java script to manage element of a iframe

```
frame.contentWindow.document.getElementById or
frame.contentDocument.getElementById
```

Comment: Not when the iframe is on a different domain to the page loaded into it, as the first line of the question says (by saying they are two different websites run by two different companies)

Comment: yeah this needs to be able to work on different domains, that is why I am kind of stumped.